# Create subset orders by comparing between columns and rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, operation

I am trying to create order numbers for subsets of data within a dataframe.  For a new column ("strike_order", I want to check that the value of the "option_expiration" column equals the value from the "option_expiration" column on the row above.  If it does not equal(ie a new subset) set value"strike_order" to 1.  if equal, set value to previous row "strike_order" +1.

The error I get at the bottom of the error message in Jupyter is KeyError: 'the label [06/15/2001] is not in the [index]'

Example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[4,1],[4,2]],columns=
["source_column","desired_output"])#, index = ["1","2","3","4","5","5"])
df

  source_column desired_output
0   2            1
1   2            2
2   2            3
3   2            4
4   4            1
5   4            2
```

ie when the source column changes value, it triggers a new count from 1 in the output column

My code is as follows:

```
def compare(i): 
   for i in df.loc[i,"source_column"]:
    if i <1  :
        return 1 #populates first row as 1

    elif  df.loc[i,"source_column"] == df.loc[i-
1,"source_column"]:
            return compare(i-1) +1
    else:
        return 1           


df["desired_output"]=df["source_column"].apply(compare)
```

Comment: If you can post more data on your questions may help!

Comment: input data file and python script now attached via link to dropbox

Comment: You're likely to get better help faster if you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with representative example data, rather than posting a link to a zip file.  In addition to making it easier for us to help you, you may find that taking the time to develop a representative, minimal example is often a good first step towards gaining clarity on your problem.

Comment: Fair comment, updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rank()

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source_column': [2,2,2,2,4,4]})
df['strike_order'] = df.groupby('source_column').source_column.rank(method = 'first')\
.astype(int)
```

You get

```
    source_column   strike_order
0   2               1
1   2               2
2   2               3
3   2               4
4   4               1
5   4               2
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called cumulative count you can do that directly like so .

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('source_column').cumcount()+1
```

```
  source_column  desired_output  new
0              2               1    1
1              2               2    2
2              2               3    3
3              2               4    4
4              4               1    1
5              4               2    2
In [453]:
```